# Google Colab File Explorer UI

Tags: google-colaboratory

How to go down on File Explorer UI in google colab?. I know the `cd` command. but I want to know how to do the same in explorer UI.

Comment: If the question has been asked before, then refer to it. Don't open duplicate questions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.